# How does a SSL certificate affect page ranking?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We have an internationally oriented business with a .com domain and all text in English. However, our SSL certificate is Dutch. 
We notice a drop in orders since changing our site and using this certificate and when searching for our products, we rank a lot higher on google.nl than on google.com, despite having a .com domain.
Does the country in the SSL certificate have any effect on page rankings?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question outside [the scope defined by the SEO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google prioritizes security the most and has come out publicly and said that they do use SSL as a ranking factor.  im sure SSL is supposed to boost your SEO. Perhaps your site has keywords that are related to Netherlands, therefore having a higher rank in .nl as compared to .com.

Nevertheless, understand that SSL is not just for SEO but its a security tool for your website that decrease the chances to be hacked or compromised.